# How to find an element that contains specific float number in Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, driver, element

I would like to find an element that contains a specific float number using Selenium Python. The specific float number such as `1.23`,`1.002`,`2.505` works fine. However, I can't work it out with float numbers such as `1.20`, `1.300`, and so on. I doubted that as long as there is zero number at the end of decimal places, I failed to get it. This is because `1.20` and `1.300` end with zero at the decimal places. (Please correct me if I am wrong.)

Here is my code:

```
f = open('myFile.txt', 'r')     
i = f.read()
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), "+str(i)+")]").click()
```

The `myFile.txt` contains a specific float number, it works fine when the decimal place of float number does not end with zero.

Any helps is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the question, just replace `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[(text()="+str(i)+")]").click()` into `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), "+str(i)+")]").click()`, problem solved!